# Track sent emails

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a button which executes mailto function through javascript.Is there any way i can track his sent mails ?

Comment: What do you mean by track? As in storing stuff to a DB and get them back?

Comment: You can save sent emails in a text file, or in a database, etc. If you want to check that emails were sent, you'll have to look at the mail service installed on the service.

Comment: tracking whether email is read by reciever or not ?if read than how many times .

Answer (score 2):

The standard method for "tracking" email is to include a resource which is not embedded in the email, and which the email client will hopefully automatically request from the server.  Then, when the request is made, you can log the request as someone opening the email.

There are a few issues with this method.  First, most email programs know about this trick and will not automatically download resources any longer (it often requires the user to force downloading), so you will only see a small portion of all emails opened.  Second, many email programs also cache these resources once open, so you might see the first time it's opened, but not each time after that.

If this is the road you want to go down, you need to generate a resource that will be served up by PHP (you might need to modify your webserver config to do this).  Images work best, since they tend to have the fewest vulnerabilities and are more trusted by end users.  You would need to server the image through PHP using a route matching rule, and then stripping out the `GET` value from the request to store in a database.  I would recommend serving up a banner image for your email with a UUID attached to each email (ex: http://example.com/resources/banner.jpg?i=45d947e2-473b-47d8-8778-9a2f9c78098c).

Comment: Thanks.The process you have mentioned above will work  .But is it possible  to integrate the above method with "mailto" html function since this function does not support  HTML content(only text) in its body therefore i cannot pass the image tag with URL  .Is there any alternative to mailto function where i can do so ?

Comment: I would recommend looking at libraries like Swift Mailer to handle HTML email generation. https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer

Comment: great, but client is adamant to have mailto functionality

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do what they are asking.  You can include Swift Mailer and then expose a single function call for them, but you are not going to be able to overload the PHP `mailto` function to do what you are wanting (at least not very easily).